# convert cycles materials to blender render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I created materials in **cycles**(assigned a color). I need convert **cycles** to **internal**, but when I do it, materials lose color and broke material(Node< none >).

How can i convert?

Thanks!

Comment: Cycles and BI materials are very different so "converting" per se is not really gonna happen. You can use scripts to transfer some of the material data, another way is to use nodes between BI and Cycles, but yeah, as the materials and engines are quite different a simple "conversion" will not happen, material will be recreated either way.

Answer (score -1):

You could try disabling the "use nodes" option.[image: Use node]

Comment: Welcome to [blender.se]. This answer may already be helpful. It would be great if you could add a little more detail as to why Internal has the use node option if it breaks the material and how the nodes in Internal and Cycles are different. It would also be good to refer to the main question **How can I convert** which probably refers to the properties of the material like colors and other parameters.